# Create not found when using Sequelize CLI generated model

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, next.js, sequelize-cli

My approach was like this below command

```
npx sequelize-cli model:generate --name User --attributes name:string,email:string,password:string
```

then it's generated a model file named `user.js` & file structure like below

```
'use strict';
const {
    Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    class User extends Model {
        /**
         * Helper method for defining associations.
         * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
         * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
         */
        static associate(models) {
            // define association here
            User.hasMany(models.Course, {
                foreignKey: 'userId'
            })
        }
    };
    User.init({
        name: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        sequelize,
        modelName: 'User',
    });
    return User;
};
```

also, created the `Users` table with columns.

And the `index.js` file like below which automatically generated

```
'use strict';
// main model file
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

and when I try to create a user like the below codes

```
import { User } from '../../../../models'

try {
    await User.create({
        name: 'john doe',
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
    })

    res.json({"message": "create"})
} catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message)
}
```

it's showing

> Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

what I have done wrong here?

Can you please help me out with that?

Thanks

Comment: `import db from '../../../../models'` and then `await db.User.create(...`

Comment: @Anatoly yes, already tried like that

Comment: Did you look at imported `db`?

Comment: @Anatoly I think I could understand the issue but don't know to resolve it! the issue is `fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)` it's failing to get directory name & this is the issue

Comment: And what does `readdirSync(__dirname)` return?

Comment: it's showing my system's root info like `application, var, www` etc... @Anatoly

Comment: It's weird. See https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname

Answer (score 0):

```
replace this code in models/index.js for printing database successfully connected or not.



    'use strict';

    const fs = require('fs');
    const path = require('path');
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    const basename = path.basename(__filename);
    const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
    const config = require(__dirname + '/../../config/config.js')[env];
    const db = {};

    let sequelize;
    if (config.use_env_variable) {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
    } else {
      sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
    }


//for checking database successfully connected or not

    sequelize
      .authenticate()
      .then(() => {

        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
      });
    fs
      .readdirSync(__dirname)
      .filter(file => {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
      })
      .forEach(file => {
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
      });

    Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
      if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
      }
    });

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

    module.exports = db;





Then try to importing like this.



const admin = require("../../database/models").tbl_admin;

try {
    await admin.create({
        name: 'john doe',
        email: 'john@gmail.com'
    })

    res.json({"message": "create"})
} catch (error) {
    res.send(error.message)
}
```